# promQL how to divide node_load by number of cores

Tags: load, prometheus, division, promql, prometheus-node-exporter

I have load.

`node_load1`

```
node_load1{group="FTP",instance="10.41.48.100:9100",job="node"} 0.1
node_load1{group="Prometheus",instance="localhost:9100",job="node"} 0.2
```

And I have number of cores for each instance

`count(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"}) by (instance)`

```
{instance="10.41.48.100:9100"}  1
{instance="localhost:9100"} 8
```

And now I need to divide it by `node` label ignoring other labels.

`node_load1 / on (instance) count(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"})`

But result is no data.
What am I doing wrong? Is not  `on(<labels>)` matching only specified labels ignoring anything else?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
node_load1 / count by (group, instance, job) (node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="idle"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Marcelo's answer shows me an empty query result.

```
sum(node_load5{}) by (instance) / count(node_cpu_seconds_total{mode="system"}) by (instance)
```